# Calculating the Jacobian of a JAX Convolution

Tags: python, math, jax, autodiff

I'm using JAX to produce a convolution

```py
def gaussian_kernel(size: int, std: float):
    """Generates a 2D Gaussian kernel."""
    x, y = jnp.mgrid[-size:size+1, -size:size+1]
    g = jnp.exp(-(x**2 + y**2) / (2 * std**2))
    return g / g.sum()
    
def gaussian_blur(image, kernel_size=5, sigma=1.0):
    """Applies Gaussian blur to a 2D image."""
    kernel = gaussian_kernel(kernel_size, sigma)
    blurred_image = convolve2d(image, kernel, mode='same')
    return blurred_image
```

Basically, just an ordinary blur.

Mathematically, I don't understand what the DERIVATIVE for a convolution will look like with respect to the input pixels.

As in, what is the effect on output pixel x from changing input pixel y.

How can I define this? How can I extract it from JAX. I dont even know where to start!

Well, I'm hoping to be able to extract the gradients with JAX for the output pixels with respect to the input pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the jacobian using [`jax.jacobian`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html):

```py
image_out = gaussian_blur(image)
image_jac = jax.jacobian(gaussian_blur)(image)
```

For an input `image` of shape `(M, N)`, `image_out` will also have shape `(M, N)`, and `image_jac` will have shape `(M, N, M, N)`.

The value `image_jac[i, j, k, l]` tells you the partial derivative of `image_out[i, j]` with respect to `image[k, l]`.